# Python vs C++ Precision

Tags: python, c++, precision

I am trying to reproduce a C++ high precision calculation in full python, but I got a slight difference and I do not understand why.

Python:

```py
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 18
r = 0 + (((Decimal(0.95)-Decimal(1.0))**2)+(Decimal(0.00403)-Decimal(0.00063))**2).sqrt()
# r = Decimal('0.0501154666744709107')
```

C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double zx2 = 0.95;
    double zx1 = 1.0;
    double zy2 = 0.00403;
    double zy1 = 0.00063;
    double r;
    r = 0.0 + sqrt((zx2-zx1)*(zx2-zx1)+(zy2-zy1)*(zy2-zy1));
    std::cout<<"r = " << r << " ****";

    return 0;
}
// r = 0.050115466674470907 ****
```

There is this `1` showing up near the end in python but not in c++, why ? Changing the precision in python will not change anything (i already tried) because, the `1` is before the "rounding".

```
Python: 0.0501154666744709107 
C++   : 0.050115466674470907
```

Edit:
I though that `Decimal` would convert anything passed to it into a string in order to "recut" them, but the comment of [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) made me doubt about it and after checking the source code, it is not the case ! So I changed to use string. Now the Python result is the same as WolframAlpha shared by [Random Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6273251/random-davis): [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=0%20%2B%20sqrt%28%28%280.95%20-%201.0%29%5E2%29%2B%280.00403-0.00063%29%5E2%29).

Comment: aren't doubles just more precise floats (i.e. more bits) while `Decimal` uses integers which gives pretty much the highest precision

Comment: C++ `double` has only ~15 digits precision. The result requires more than 15 digits.

Comment: It's expected that floating-point arithmetic results may differ from fixed-point results.

Comment: The difference seems meaningless; you're already in the realms of floating point errors at that point. Wolfram Alpha says the number is `0.0501154666744708663...` ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=0+%2B+sqrt%28%28%280.95+-+1.0%29%5E2%29%2B%280.00403-0.00063%29%5E2%29)). Your results are diverging after 15 decimal places, which is about the limit of precision of doubles.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html "Decimal numbers can be represented exactly. In contrast, numbers like 1.1 and 2.2 do not have exact representations in binary floating point."

Comment: **don't pass floats to `Decimal`**. That defeats the entire purpose

Comment: If you want to reproduce the C++ behaviour in Python then, in Python, you need to use binary (base 2 mantissa) floating point, not `Decimal`.      In Python, the `float` type is equivalent to C++ `double` (assuming your C++ implementation uses IEEE-754 floating point, which is common in practice but not universal).   `Decimal` can represent values like `0.1` exactly, which floating point types like C++s `double` cannot do, so aq lot of operations involving `Decimal` do not give the same result as C++ using `double`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The origin of the discrepancy is that Python `Decimal` follows the more modern IBM's [*General Decimal Arithmetic Specification*](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decarith.html).

In C++ however there too exist support available for 80-bit "[extended precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision)" through the `long double` format.

For reference, the standard IEEE-754 floating point `double`s contain 53 bits of precision.

Here below the C++ example from the question, refactored using `long double`s:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    long double zx2 = 0.95;
    long double zx1 = 1.0;
    long double zy2 = 0.00403;
    long double zy1 = 0.00063;
    long double r;
    r = 0.0 + sqrt((zx2-zx1)*(zx2-zx1)+(zy2-zy1)*(zy2-zy1));
    std::fixed;
    std::cout<< std::setprecision(25) << "r = " << r << " ****";  //25 floats
    // prints "r = 0.05011546667447091067728042 ****"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But according to the comment of Random Davis under the question, wolfram says the result should be `0.0501154666744708663... `. Thus, if wolfram is correct, the c++ long double should tend to this one no ?

Comment: @Taknok may be an issue related to how more exact Wolfram is in computing the `sqrt`. Try an example with just arithmetic operators to check if results match.

Comment: @Taknok results between C++ and Mathematica also differ in the case of using only arithmetic expression. They start to diverge at the 12th decimal place, give or take. Considering Wolfram claims they can represent real numbers up to any precision https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RepresentationOfNumbers.html , it must be C++ accumulating floating point errors due to the impossibility of correctly representing most decimal numbers within a binary-based system, see a good explanation of this in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out by [@juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73144724/python-vs-c-precision#comment129185420_73144724), in your Python script you are passing `float`s to the constructors of `Decimal`s. This defeats the entire purpose of `Decimal` since the `float` that gets passed in may not have a perfect binary representation; and it's that binary representation that's passed into the constructor, not what you actually typed.

So, the solution is to just add quotes around everything, so that the `Decimal` has a complete understanding of what you typed:

```py
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 30 #increased precision for demo purposes
r = 0 + (((Decimal('0.95')-Decimal('1.0'))**Decimal('2'))+(Decimal('0.00403')-Decimal('0.00063'))**Decimal('2')).sqrt()
print(r)
```

Output:

```
0.0501154666744708663897193971169
```

Versus Wolfram Alpha:

```
0.0501154666744708663897193971168629...
```

So, clearly the output here is correct; more so than C++ or if you pass `float`s to the `Decimal`s in the Python script. Clearly the C++ script is suffering from an accumulation of errors, probably rounding errors.